# Routing error in ajax on ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have this in my .html.erb code:

```
 $.ajax({
 url: "/timeMachineEdit",
 data: {editTimeMachine: newArray},
 type: 'POST',
 success: function (res) {
     if (res.result === 'ok') {
     alert('Data saved');
     } else {
     alert('Save error');
     }
},
error: function () {
     alert('Save error.');
     }
});
```

This in my datasets_controller.rb

```
def timeMachineEdit 
    @dataset = current_user.dataset
    @dataset.machine_time = params[:editTimeMachine]
end
```

And in my routes.rb:

```
match "/timeMachineEdit", to: "datasets#timeMachineEdit"
```

But when is submited shows:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/timeMachineEdit 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Where is the problem here?
is the routes in the ajax url or something else?

Comment: you have a typo: `match "/tiempoMaquinaEdit",`: tiempoMaquinaEdit should be `match "/timeMachineEdit"`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your route definition....

try match "/timeMachineEdit", to: "datasets#timeMachineEdit"

I think, it will still not work because of the nature of format..In the datasets_controller try the following code...

```
def timeMachineEdit 
  @dataset = current_user.dataset
  @dataset.machine_time = params[:editTimeMachine]
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js 
  end
end
```

Also change the dataType of your AJAX request to "script" in order to correctly match it with format.js else the format will be */* which will select the first format that you will specify in the respond_to block..